# How to disable UFW on Ubuntu after locking out SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, firewall

I enabled the UFW firewall using SSH on my server at Digital Ocean running `sudo ufw enable`. and forgot to allow the ports for SSH, FTP, ... (but allowed port 80).

How can I SSH into the server or reset the firewall? Now I can't do anything, neither through SSH nor through FTP.

The root account is enabled and I know it's password, I also know the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The question is incredibly ambiguous. Is the firewall on the box, or somewhere in between?

In either case, you need to gain access to the virtual or real keyboard.
If it's an ec2 box, use AWS UI. If its a virtual box, use VirtualBox UI.